# A path of a stochastic process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider the process: 
$$Y_t = W_t + \mathbb{P}(W_t > 0),$$ where is Brownian motion.

What is a sample path of this process $Y_t(\omega)$?

When we fix $\omega$, should it be also fixed for $\mathbb{P}(W_t > 0)$ that means it becomes either 0 or 1?

Comment: Huh? $Y_t=W_t+g(t)$ where $g$ is deterministic and, for every $t$, $g(t)=P(W_t>0)$. (Oh, and it happens that $g(t)=\frac12$ for every $t$, but this is not necessary to understand your setting.)

Comment: Is the same for $Y_t = W_t + \mathbb{P}(Y_t > 0)$?

Comment: This would be what they call a circular definition, right? If $Y_t=W_t+g(t)$ then $P(Y_t>0)=P(W_t>-g(t))=P(W_t<g(t))=\Phi(g(t)/\sqrt{t})$  (*can you show this?*) hence you are asking that $g(t)=\Phi(g(t)/\sqrt{t})$. Indeed it happens that, for each fixed $t>0$, the equation $u=\Phi(u/\sqrt{t})$ has a unique solution $u>0$ (*can you show this?*) hence your identity defines uniquely $g(t)$ for every $t$... But is this really what you have in mind?

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation.